# Yodlee process MFA with null mfaInfo.fieldInfo

Tags: yodlee

According to

https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/API_Flow/Refresh_Account

once I've received response with isMessageAvailable = true and errorCode is empty I should call getMFAResponse (actually I'm using getMFAResponseForSite)

this response should contain not null mfaRefreshInfo.fieldInfo. Unfortunately all cases I was able to test fieldInfo were null.

Could you please help me to understand what I'm doing wrong. SiteAccountId is 10038630.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using getMFAResponseForSite then use this [refresh flow](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/API_Flow/Refresh_Site_Account)

Now response of getMFAResponseForSite depends upon how soon yodlee encounters the MFA after login attempt.

There are 3 types of responses you can get -

```
  { "isMessageAvailable": false, "timeOutTime": 0, "itemId": 0,
 "memSiteAccId": 10000502, "retry": true }
```

On your 1st call to the MFA API you may get this if there is a delay in bringing the MFA data , hence you need to go back and call this API again (as suggested in the flow to loop).In this case if with messageAvailable if false and timeoutTime > 0 then it means that Yodlee has timed out the request and you can abort the refresh and try re-initiating it.

```
{
   "isMessageAvailable": true,
  "fieldInfo": {
    "responseFieldType": "text",
    "minimumLength": -1,
    "maximumLength": 6,
    "displayString": "Security Key"
  },
  "timeOutTime": 97640,
  "itemId": 0,
  "memSiteAccId": 10000052,
  "retry": false
}
```

This is the case where you get the MFA response. Here you can see that isMessageAvailable is true and you have field info populated. This response can come at 1st call of getMFAResponseForSite or after 1 or 2 loops.

```
{
  "isMessageAvailable": true,
  "fieldInfo": {
    "questionAndAnswerValues": [],
    "numOfMandatoryQuestions": -1
  },
  "timeOutTime": 98480,
  "itemId": 0,
  "errorCode": 0,
  "memSiteAccId": 10039332,
  "retry": false
}
```

In this case you can see that there is an error code present, if it's 0(zero) that means login was successful without MFA and Yodlee is able to navigate to account summary page. In case error code is non zero then please refer [error code](https://developer.yodlee.com/FAQs/Error_Codes) page

Now in your case the siteAccountID is failing with error code 429 and hence you should be getting that information in getMFAResponseForSite API.

can you make sure you are following the right refresh flow and making the right API calls as ideally the behavior will not change from what is represented in the flow diagram.

Comment: the only problem with diagram is that I understand it as I need to call getMFAResponseForSite again when I receive response type 2. Aster call getMFAResponseForSite once again I received fieldInfo as null. After I eliminated additional getMFAResponseForSite call it stared working.

Comment: Actually when you see the diagram it says after you get response type 2 , you need to present the MFA to the user and then pass the answer to Yodlee using putMFARequestForSite after this step you need to call getMFAResponseForSite again.